# Create controller with existing database and entity framework

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

hello I'm new in MVC and my project is CMS
I read some articles about mvc and I understand the code first concept.

My question is how to create controllers with existing Entity Framework? My colleagues here said that :

> It should create an empty controller and create a new model for that controller but I don't know how.

Please help.

this are the codes generated when i added the controller with datacontext and model.

private SureSeatsDBEntities db = new SureSeatsDBEntities();

```
    //
    // GET: /Users/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.SystemUsers.ToList());
    }

    //
    // GET: /Users/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        SystemUser systemuser = db.SystemUsers.Find(id);
        if (systemuser == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(systemuser);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Users/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Users/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(SystemUser systemuser)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.SystemUsers.Add(systemuser);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(systemuser);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Users/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        SystemUser systemuser = db.SystemUsers.Find(id);
        if (systemuser == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(systemuser);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Users/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(SystemUser systemuser)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(systemuser).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(systemuser);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Users/Delete/5

    public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
    {
        SystemUser systemuser = db.SystemUsers.Find(id);
        if (systemuser == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(systemuser);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Users/Delete/5

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        SystemUser systemuser = db.SystemUsers.Find(id);
        db.SystemUsers.Remove(systemuser);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your ASP .NET MVC web application you will need to create a new controller. You do this  by right clicking on the "Controllers" folder and navigating to "Add" -> "Controller". Specify your controller name and it will be created.

ASP .NET MVC controllers are not dependent on Entity Framework models unless you make them. You should create a view model for your controller, which is just a representation of what data is displayed on that page.

I suggest you do some searching to fill in the gaps. Things you may want to look up are "model view controller pattern".

[This series of tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started) is also a good starting point for learning all about ASP .NET MVC.

Comment: we have and existing entity framework. so do i need to create a model or not?

Comment: You will need to create a view model for your ASP .NET controller, yes.

Comment: am i doing right? i created a controller and specified the model and datacontext needed and it generates a create,delete,details,edit and index view and now im editing the view to make it look nicer.

Comment: @DanielCrisostomo That sounds about right. Edit your original post and add code that you have and I will let you know.

Comment: @DanielCrisostomo That looks about right. There are some improvements you could do but nothing too major.

Comment: how about can i create my class for inserting record? how to do that?

Comment: @DanielCrisostomo Well, that's a different question in itself. We've solved this question it looks like. If you make another question asking specifically about your insertion class and post some code, others will likely respond. I might even see it and respond. So if this one is solved, you should mark it and ask an additional question. That way we keep the topics concise and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create the Models if you are using the **Entity Framework** as it will take care for you. And regarding the controller you do this by right clicking on the "Controllers" folder and navigating to

> Add -> Controller

State your controller name and it will be created.